# Navigation of screen based on use rrole in react native mobile application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on the mobile application on react native framework, I could not navigate into different screens based on the user role, can anyone please help me to do this with some source codes. I am a beginner in react native and will be really thankful if someone helps me to overcome this issue.

Looking forward to your help
Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do ?

Comment: For example, i have login.js and App.js. after login successfully I have to redirect to different screen based on the user role, i will share code with you, if you give your details.

Comment: can I have ur details or i can contact you personally so that I can share my code with you?

Comment: It's difficult to help without some code samples and/or an explanation of what you've tried to solve your problem. Feel free to copy/paste the code from you `App.js` and `login.js` files as part of your question and you might get more answers

Comment: my code is too large so i could not copy and paste here, i will share personally if you want to help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [code](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) **from the react navigation** as an example.

It only checks if you have an access_token but **you can adapt it by checking the propriety of your user** to select the screen available to him.

An [example](https://github.com/docmurloc/doc-music/blob/master/docMusic/Navigation/Navigation.js) with a project.